# Performing a left join across a many-to-many table with conditions

Tags: sql, mysql

**General Case**

How do you perform a left join across a many-to-many relationship when you want to add a condition to the foreign side of the relation?

**Specific Case**

We're dealing with two tables: `team` and `pool`. There is also a `team_pool` table serving as a many-to-many junction table between them. Additionally, a `pool` has a `stage_id` column.

I want to retrieve all teams with that team's pool for a specific stage. If the pool doesn't exist, I want the pool to be NULL. Sample, idealized results:

```
+--------+----------+------+
| team   | stage_id | pool |
+--------+----------+------+
| Team 1 |        2 | C    |
| Team 2 |     NULL | NULL | //this team doesn't belong to a pool for this stage (but it could belong to a pool for a different stage)
| Team 3 |        2 | G    |
| Team 3 |        2 | H    | //if a team belongs to a 2 pools for the same stage
| Team 4 |        2 | D    |
```

If it's relevant, I'm using MySQL.

**SQL**

Here's the (simplified) SQL used to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE team (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE team_pool (team_id BIGINT, pool_id BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY(team_id, pool_id));
CREATE TABLE pool (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, stage_id BIGINT, name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

**Ideal Solution**

The ideal solution would:

- Not require a change to my schema (ORM really wants it this way)
- Require a single, non UNION query.

**Attempted solutions**

- Use an INNER JOIN rather than a LEFT JOIN from `team` to `team_pool` and `team_pool` to `pool`. Issue: we lose teams that don't belong to a pool
- LEFT JOIN from `team` to `team_pool` and `team_pool` to `pool` using a WITH condition that the `stage_id` on `pool` matches what we're looking for. Issue: when a team belongs to many pools, we get multiple results. Adding a GROUP BY doesn't help.

**EDIT: Chosen Solution**

There are a lot of good solutions here.

Given that my ideal solution is not possible, I'd rather add `stage_id` to team_pool than use UNION or subqueries. This has the added benefit of letting me enforce that a team can only belong to one pool per stage. It also makes the queries simple:

```
SELECT t.name, p.name, tp.stage_id FROM team t LEFT JOIN team_pool tp ON t.id = tp.team_id AND tp.stage_id = 2 LEFT JOIN pool p ON p.id = tp.pool_id
```

Comment: How does Team 2 have a stage_id if pool is null?

Comment: Can you add to your idealized results to show what you expect if a team belongs to many pools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the concepts behind your schema, then I would think `stage_id` should be a column in `team_pool` rather than `pool`.  The stage is not an attribute of the pool, it is a factor in the mapping of teams to pools, right?

Regardless, this is how I would write your query in Oracle.  I'm not sure if this exact syntax is right for MySQL.  Presumably you would want to parameterize the literal value for `stage_id`.

```
SELECT t.name, p.name
  FROM (SELECT team.name, pool_id
          FROM team LEFT JOIN team_pool
            ON team_pool.team_id = team.team_id ) t
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT pool_id, name FROM pool WHERE stage_id = 2) p
            ON p.pool_id = t.pool_id
```

Comment: The stage is an attribute of the pool (pools exist for a certain stage). If the choice is between a UNION and adding stage_id to team_pool, I'll choose the latter. The primary reason I was avoiding adding stage_id to team_pool is because the ORM I'm using makes it a little annoying to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it's not possible to fulfill all your criteria.

Longer answer: it's very possible to get all your results with a UNION. The first half will show teams that do have a pool for that stage; the second will show teams that do not.

```
select ...
from team
left join team_pool 
   on team.id = team_pool.team_id
left-join pool 
   on pool.id = team_pool.pool_id 
      and pool.stage_id = @stage
UNION
select distinct team.id, @stage, NULL
from team
where not exists 
   (select pool_id 
      from pool
      inner join team_pool
         on team_pool.pool_id = pool.pool_id 
      where team_pool.team_id = team.id 
         and pool.stage_id = @stage
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for just one stage, you can left join the tables together.  The pool name will be null if no pool is found. For example, for `stage = 2`:

```
select  t.name, 2, pool.name
from    team t
left join
        (
        select  team_id, p.name
        from    team_pool tp
        join    pool p
        on      tp.pool_id = p.id
        where   p.stage_id = 2
        ) pool
on      pool.team_id = t.id
```

If you'd like to query all stages, you could use a `cross join` to generate one row for each team-stage combination.  The left join then searches for a pool for each row:

```
select  t.name, s.stage_id, p.name
from    team t
cross join
        (
        select  distinct stage_id
        from    pool
        ) s
left join
        (
        select  tp.team_id, p.stage_id, p.name
        from    team_pool tp
        join    pool p
        on      tp.pool_id = p.id
        ) pool
on      pool.team_id = t.id
        and pool.stage_id = s.stage_id
```

Because `stage_id` comes from the cross join, it will not be `null` if no pool is found.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this will work since I don't have a database I can play around with right now, but I think this should work.  Basically create two left joined "table", then left join them again.  If it does work, I can't imagine it would be very performant.

***UPDATE***
Simplified the SQL

```
SELECT t.name, p.stage_id, p.pool_name
FROM team t 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT pool.name as pool_name, pool.stage_id, team_pool.team_id as junc_team_id
    FROM pool LEFT JOIN team_pool
    ON team_pool.pool_id = pool.pool_id) p
ON p.junc_team_id = t.team_id
```

Comment: Summary of SQL: Join pool and team_pool together to act like a single table, then left join team to that new pseudo table using team_id.  Joining pool to team_pool could probably use an INNER JOIN; it's simply a way to get the team_id linked to the pool_id.  Once that is established, then you should be able to link the team.team_id to any p.team_id without duplicates (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Just so we're clear:

You want to provide a team and a stage

You want to return:
All teams sharing any pool with your provided team in the provided stage
All teams with no pool in the provided stage
all pool/team combo for any team sharing any pool with your provided team in the provided stage?

I am pretty sure this can be accomplished without `UNION` but I'm not entirely clear on what results you're after

As a starter, IMO:

Your initial select should be on teams table

You should add criteria for pool in the `JOIN` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause

You should join again on the teams table once you have a desired stage to introduce all of that teams pools