# SQLAlchemy: complex ON clause when performing LEFT JOIN on many-to-many relation

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, left-join, outer-join

Is there any way to extend the `ON` clause with dynamic filters when performing JOIN on many-to-many relations?

I've found good related question on StackOverflow: "[Performing a left join across a many-to-many table with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841707/performing-a-left-join-across-a-many-to-many-table-with-conditions)". Unfortunately that question is about raw SQL and just describes the same issue. I haven't found any good solution how to implement this in SQLAlchemy.

Ok, let me describe the environment. Suppose there are two tables:

```py
Model = declarative_base()

M2M = Table('m2m', Model.metadata,
            Column('book_id', Integer, ForeignKey(...)),
            Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey(...)),

class Book(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    authors = relation('Author',
                       secondary=M2M,
                       back_populates='books')

class Author(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    books = relation('Book',
                     secondary=M2M,
                     back_populates='authors')
```

Let's create some authors and then assign some books to them:

```py
A1 = Author()  # id: 1
A2 = Author()  # id: 2
A3 = Author()  # id: 3

B1 = Book(authors=[A1, A2])  # id: 1
B2 = Book(authors=[A2])      # id: 2
B3 = Book(authors=[A3])      # id: 3
```

Well, now I want to get Books with ids in [1,3] outerjoined Authors with ids in [1,2]. I mean, I want to get Books B1 and B2 with loaded Author iff Author ID is in kind of "allowed-ids" list. Such list of allowed ids is created by outside code, so I can't use it to build `primaryjoin` or `secondaryjoin` relation filters, list of allowed ids is generated outside dynamically.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841707/performing-a-left-join-across-a-many-to-many-table-with-conditions), the following query would help:

```sql
SELECT books.id, authors.id
FROM books
LEFT JOIN m2m ON (
    books.id = m2m.book_id
    AND m2m.author_id IN (1,2)) -- allowed author ids!
LEFT JOIN authors ON author.id = m2m.author_id
WHERE books.id IN (1,3) -- and any another filter
;

-- result:
--  books.id | authors.id
--  ---------+-----------
--         1 |          1
--         1 |          2
--         3 |       null
```

But I don't know how to create such query using SQLAlchemy. The documentation describes solutions based on subqueries only.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
book_ids = [1, 3]
author_ids = [1, 2]

q = (session.query(Book.id, Author.id)
     .outerjoin(M2M, and_(Book.id == M2M.c.book_id, M2M.c.author_id.in_(author_ids)))
     .outerjoin(Author, M2M.c.author_id == Author.id)
     .filter(Book.id.in_(book_ids))
     )
```

However, I think that the below should produce the same result with one `JOIN` less:

```
q = (session.query(Book.id, M2M.c.author_id)
     .outerjoin(M2M, and_(Book.id == M2M.c.book_id, M2M.c.author_id.in_(author_ids)))
     .filter(Book.id.in_(book_ids))
     )
```